# What does it mean when the Embassy returns my passport one week after my interview?

Tags: visas, study, application-status, schengen-visas

After my visa interview and submission of my visa application documents with the German Embassy, I was called exactly a week later to go get my passport.
...#i submitted my documents as was requested.
I applied for a students' visa.
I was asked to add some additional named documents.
I submitted the documents in the 6th day.
I was called on the following day(seventh day) to go for my passport.
That is it.

Does that mean my student visa application has been denied?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't think we can answer this without speculating. Your best bet is to actually go pick up the passport and see for yourself what the status of your application is.

Comment: This is post-submission anxiety. Nothing to be done about it.

Comment: It means they are returning your passport.

Answer (score 3):

It means they have reached a decision and you will find out what it is when you pick up your passport. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: A decision in just one week??

Comment: @Aroma: Why not? The processing delay is not taken up by people thinking deep thoughts about the application -- mostly just by the papers sitting around in a queue until a qualified decisionmaker has time to take at look at them.